# RLS filter with multiple values assigned?

Tags: powerbi, dax, row-level-security

I need to filter my Power BI report by the App IDs associated with the current user (using the USERPRINCIPALNAME function). So I have three tables in my model, DimApp, DimUser, and FactRegisters, where a User_Id may be related to 1 or more App_Ids in my Fact table.

DimApp table
[image: DimApp table]

DimUser table
[image: DimUser table]

FactRegister table
[image: FactRegisters table]

As you can see in FactRegisters table there are two App_Ids (3 and 1) for User_Id 201. The following is the DAX rule defined in App_Id column from DimApp table to filter the data:

```
VAR userId =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    DimUser[User_Id],
    DimUser[Email], USERPRINCIPALNAME()
)
VAR app = 
LOOKUPVALUE ( 
    FactRegisters[Application_Id],
    FactRegisters[User_Id], userId
)
RETURN DimApplication[Application_Id] IN {app}
```

Verifying the DAX expression doesn't return an error, however, when I choose to "View as" that role I'm not able to see the data in the visuals. The error states: "Couldn't load the data for this visual. An error was encountered during the evaluation of the row-level security expression defined in table DimApp. A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

Cannot display the visual viewing as role
[image: Cannot display the visual viewing as role]

However, when a single App_Id is associated with the User_Id, I'm able to visualize the data on the report visuals using the same DAX rule. Here is how FactRegisters table looks like when User_Id 201 has a single App_Id (3) associated:

FactRegisters table when User_Id with single App_Id
[image: FactRegisters table when User_Id with single App_Id]

User_Id with a single App_Id visual
[image: User_Id with a single App_Id visual]

Now I'm I able to visualize data in the report. This is not a suitable case scenario as a User_Id can have many App_Ids.

I also tried the following static DAX rule in my App_Id column from DimApp just to test and pass multiple values to that column, and I succeed in visualizing data for multiple App_Ids:

```
DimApplication[Application_Id] IN {1,3}
```

Static RLS with multiple values by App_Id column
[image: Static RLS with multiple values by App_Id column]

But this is not the goal (it's not dynamic). The goal is to visualize the data from all the Apps associated with the current user. Is it possible? Can't I pass more than one value to a column while filtering in RLS?

Answer (score 1):

```
[Application_Id] IN 

CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('FactRegister'[Application_Id]),
    FILTER ('FactRegister',
       'FactRegister'[User_Id] = 
        LOOKUPVALUE (DimUser[User_Id], DimUser[Email],USERPRINCIPALNAME())
    )
)
```